# How do you multiply a QString, so it repeats itself n times?

Tags: qt, qstring

I need my string to repeat n amount of times, something like this:

```
QString s("Dog");
qDebug() << s * 3;
"DogDogDog"
```

I know you can do it with single `char`'s, but I can't figure out how to do it with strings, without resorting to creating a for loop like this:

https://paste.fedoraproject.org/300131/94336814/

Any shortcuts?

Comment: Comments removed, response added. It was a matter to go over the official documentation.

Comment: "*I know you can do it with single char's*" What? No you can't. Multiplying a char by an integer multiplies its ASCII code. Or did I misunderstand your sentence?'

Comment: @DonaldDuck 8 years ago, I was a very new programmer. I might have been talking about QChars.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`QString` simply has not such an operator (see the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)), so you can't use `operator*` to do that.

Anyway, `QString` has an interesting method called [repeated](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#repeated).
I cite the documentation, that is quite exhaustive:

> Returns a copy of this string repeated the specified number of times.
>
> If times is less than 1, an empty string is returned.

It follows an example, once more from the official documentation:

```
QString str("ab");
str.repeated(4); // returns "abababab"
```

I guess this solves your problem and it seems to be the more concise solution available.